# 'wp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: wp-cli, windows

I can't get WP-CLI to run on Windows.

- Downloaded `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar` to `c:\wp-cli\wp-cli.phar`,
- Added `c:\wp-cli\` to the System & User Path variable,
- Opened a new CMD window, ran `wp --info`, received:

> 'wp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Help appreciated.

[image: Added c:\wp-cli\ to the System & User Path variable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation on [make.wordpress.com](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/#installing-on-windows), you need to create a file called `wp.bat` located in your `C:\wp-cli` folder, with the following contents:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "c:/wp-cli/wp-cli.phar" %*
```

Once you have this set up, you should be able to use `wp` to execute WP-CLI, presuming you have PHP installed.